# image upload using multer, reactjs, nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```js
// nodejs
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.body.name);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json("File has been uploaded");
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server running ...");
});

// reactjs

const [file, setFile] = useState("");

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", file);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

// jsx

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <input type="file" name="file" onChange={handleChange} />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Hello, please I have an issue with running this code using react, it works perfectly using postman but gives this error while using react `"POSThttp://localhost:3000/api/upload [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 116ms]"`, I added "proxy": "http://localhost:5000" on the client package.json file and I also use concurrently to run both the nodejs server and react app

here is the error from node

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
[0]     at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nodejs\imageupload\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
[0]     at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nodejs\imageupload\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
[0]     at Busboy.emit (events.js:315:20)
[0]     at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nodejs\imageupload\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
[0]     at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nodejs\imageupload\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
[0]     at PartStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
[0]     at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nodejs\imageupload\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
[0]     at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:315:20)
[0]     at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nodejs\imageupload\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
[0]     at SBMH.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\nodejs\imageupload\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
```

Comment: That error code is from react, but the error is happening in your server (500 code) – can you add the error logging from your node console?

Comment: here is the error

Comment: try this: const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000"/api/upload", formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },

Comment: it gives this error i tried it = Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/api/upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the backend you're using `upload.single("file")`, in the client, you should change to :

```
    formData.append("file", file); // instead of formData.append("name", file);
```

Another solution is to use the code generated by Postman if you have the correct result in this tool. The button </> is on the right bar.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the header from the Axios request.

```
const res = await axios.post("/api/upload", formData);
```

Comment: still gives this error = POSThttp://localhost:3000/api/upload
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 15ms